# Is $A+(A^{−1})^{*}$ invertible?

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ invertible matrix.
I think this is true because I have tried a few different real and complex matrices and they satisfy this.

The trouble I'm having is showing it is true.
I started by left multiplying A* to get
$A^{*}A+A^{*}(A^{-1})^{*}$

I thought it would be helpful since $A^{*}A$ is invertible, but I'm still stuck.

Perhaps there is a counterexample that I am not seeing.

Comment: What is $A$*? $A$ adjugated?

Comment: @DanielP presumably it's the complex conjugate transpose, i.e. $B^*=(\overline{B})^T$.

Comment: Yes it is, I should have stated that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(A^{-1})^*=(A^*)^{-1}$. So after you multiply by $A^*$ on the left, you have 
$$
A^*A+I. 
$$
This is always invertible, since $A^*A$ is positive semidefinite and so $A^*A+I$ has all its (real) eigenvalues $1$ or greater. So
$$
A^*(A+(A^{-1})^*)
$$
is invertible. The only way for a product of invertible matrices to be invertible is if both are invertible.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Although, I do believe $A^{*}A$ is positive definite since A is invertible, not that it makes a difference here.

Comment: Yes, of course. I come from an operator algebras background, so in my head it's just "positive". I need to "translate" when it comes to talk about matrices.